# How to upload file (image) to NodeJS (and from NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, express, post, fetch, form-data

I have the following code:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("filedata", myImage);

fetch("/extension/api/uploadtofb", {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData
})
```

If `myImage` is a base64 string representation (dataURL) of an image, `multer` considers it not as a file but as a text. Therefore it is found in `req.body`, not in `req.file`. **How can I upload this image to my NodeJS (Express) server so it can be recognized and read as an image?** (Doesn't need to use `multer`, I just followed instructions I found so far.)

I was able to work around it by converting the base64 string to `blob` and send it as `blob` instead. The image now can be correctly found in the `req.file`. But I need to send a post request with this image from the NodeJS (Express) server. FormData doesn't accept `req.file` or `req.file.buffer`in append. **How can I convert received blob to a format, that can be accepted by FormData and sent with POST request?**

I think that if the first problem can be solved, the second problem will also solve itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly upload base64 image data

```
var base64Data = JSON.parse(res.body).data;
var filename = "test.png";
    var base64_attachement = base64Data.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/').replace(/ /g, '+');
    filepath = (__dirname + './../../public/temp');

    if (!fs.existsSync(filepath)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(filepath, 0744);    //Set Folder Permission
    }
    filepath = filepath + '/' + _filename;
    //TempFilePath
    require("fs").writeFile(filepath, base64_attachement, 'base64', function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return cb(filepath);
    });
```